# How to combine the dataset which is made by myself with the fashion mnist dataset and training together

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to ask about how to combine the dataset which is made by myself with the fashion mnist dataset and training together.

I've successfully training the dataset from fashion mnist and it can output the predictions.

Now I want to combine the dataset which is made by myself with the fashion mnist dataset and training together to output the predictions.

I've browsed many websites and found that I've use JPG-PNG-to-MNIST-NN-Format first to make my data into "idx-ubyte", this part I've already finished.

The next step it seems that I need to merge my dataset with Fashion MNIST dataset.

If you know anything that can help me, please let me know  or you can also give the informations from any website that can help me.
Thank you soooooo much.

Here is my code of the merge dataset

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gzip
import os
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

zhfont = matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/Users/yan/Downloads/fashion-mnist-master/SimHei.ttf')

 # my dataset
def read_data():
    files = [
      'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz',
      't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'
    ]
    # 我在當前的目錄下建立資料夾，裡面放入上面的四個壓縮檔案
    current = '/Users/yan/Desktop/graduation/'
    paths = []
    for i in range(len(files)):
         paths.append('/Users/yan/Desktop/graduation/'+ files[i])
    
    with gzip.open(paths[0], 'rb') as lbpath:
        y_train = np.frombuffer(lbpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=8)

    with gzip.open(paths[1], 'rb') as imgpath:
        x_train = np.frombuffer(
            imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_train), 28, 28)

    with gzip.open(paths[2], 'rb') as lbpath:
        y_test = np.frombuffer(lbpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=8)

    with gzip.open(paths[3], 'rb') as imgpath:
        x_test = np.frombuffer(
            imgpath.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(len(y_test), 28, 28)

    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)

(train_images_new, train_labels_new), (test_images_new, test_labels_new) = (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)

#read Fashion MNIST dataset and name it old
(train_images_old, train_labels_old), (test_images_old, test_labels_old) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_images_old = train_images_old.reshape(train_images_old.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
test_images_old = test_images_old.reshape(test_images_old.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
 
train_images, train_labels, test_images, test_labels = [None, None, None, None]
 
if type(train_images_old) == type(train_images_new):
    print("Type is same, concat/merge datasets...")
    train_images = np.concatenate((train_images_new, train_images_old))
    train_labels = np.concatenate((train_labels_new, train_labels_old))
     
    test_images = np.concatenate((test_images_new, test_images_old))
    test_labels = np.concatenate((test_labels_new, test_labels_old))
    print("Merge successed.")

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = read_data()
```

Comment: It's a dataframe right? Can't you just add each row to `(train_images_old, train_labels_old), (test_images_old, test_labels_old)`?

Comment: @Djinn what do you mean you mean x_test = (train_images_old, train_labels_old), (test_images_old, test_labels_old) ?

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? What's the issue?